# Using switch/case with malloc()

Tags: c, string, switch-statement, malloc

I am trying to write a code to add patients to a list. It is a large code but I am having a problem with a specific part which is to enter the patient's name. I could enter the names properly but when I tried to put my code inside a switch/case it stopped working properly. I was wondering if someone here can help.

Initially I thought maybe malloc is causing the problem but it seems to be working fine without the switch/case.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef unsigned long int u32;
typedef unsigned char u8;
typedef struct Patient patient;
struct Patient
{
    u8* name;
    patient* next;
};

void addfirstpatient(u8* name);
void addpatient(u8* name);
void print (void);
patient* head;
u8 length = 0;

int main()
{
    u32 x = 1;

    switch(x)
    {
        u8* name = malloc(20*sizeof(u8));
        case 1:
        printf("\nPlease enter patient name:");
        scanf("%s",name);
        if(length == 0)
        {
            addfirstpatient(name);
        }
        else
        {
            addpatient(name);
        }
        print();
        printf("\nPatient added , Thank you\n");
        printf("\nTo add another patient press 1");
        scanf("%d",&x);
        break;

        case 2:
        break;

        default:
        printf("\nentered default");
    }

return 0;
}

void addfirstpatient(u8* name)
{
    printf("\nadding first patient: ");
    head = (patient*)malloc(sizeof(patient));
    head->next = NULL;
    head->name = name;

    length++;
}

void addpatient(u8* name)
{
    patient* ptr = head;
    while((ptr->next)!=NULL)
    {
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    printf("\nadding patient");
     ptr->next = (patient*)malloc(sizeof(patient));
    (ptr->next)->next = NULL;
    (ptr->next)->name = name;
    length++;
}

void print (void)
{
    patient *ptr = head;
    u32 count = 1;
    printf("\n---------------------");
    if (ptr == NULL)
    {
        printf ("\nList is empty");
    }
    while (ptr!=NULL)
    {
        printf("\npatient Number %d\nname:%s" ,count,ptr->name);
        ptr = ptr->next;
        count++;
    }
    printf("\n---------------------");
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Turn up your compiler warnings and treat them as errors. You should be told that the `malloc` line without a case label will never execute.

Comment: [Can I put code outside of cases in a switch?](//stackoverflow.com/q/29023601)

Comment: What do you mean, it stopped working? Are you getting compiler errors? Run-time errors? A crash? Please cut and paste any such messages into the question

Comment: Note that `scanf("%s",name);` is a black hole waiting to devour the first person who enters more than 19 characters. `scanf("%19s",name);` would be safer.

Answer (score 2):

```
   switch(x)
    {
        u8* name = malloc(20*sizeof(u8));
        case 1:
```

Is not legal - surprised it compiles (maybe it doesnt, maybe thats your error). You need

```
   u8* name = malloc(20*sizeof(u8));
   switch(x)
    {
        case 1:
```

or maybe

```
 u8* name = NULL;
   switch(x)
    {
        case 1:
           name = malloc(20*sizeof(u8));
```

depending on when you want that array allocated

And of course you should check the return of malloc.

Comment: Shouldn't it actually be inside `case 1:` so as not to cause a memory leak?

Comment: It can be if it only happens when x = 1. But how the original code is set up it seems as tho this is supposed to happen with each case.

Comment: maybe not illegal but its never going to execute, so the compiler should flag it as unreachable code

Comment: You can't put a declaration after a label.  GCC complains: `error: a label can only be part of a statement and a declaration is not a statement`.

Answer (score 2):

Although a construction such as your ...

> ```
>    switch(x)
>     {
>         u8* name = malloc(20*sizeof(u8));
>         case 1:
> ```

... is technically legal, it does not achieve what you want.  It *does* declare variable `name`, which is then in scope throughout the body of the `switch`, but execution always skips to a `case` or `default` label if it enters the body at all, so the initializer (containing the `malloc()` call) is never evaluated and no initial value is ever assigned to variable `name`.

How you should actually proceed depends on what you want to accomplish.  If you only want variable `name` within one `case`, then it might make more sense to declare and initialize it there, but you cannot do so immediately after a label.  You could either enclose it in its own block or put an executable statement between, however:

```
   switch(x) {
       case 1: {
           u8* name = malloc(20*sizeof(u8));
           // ...
       }
       // ...
```

If you want it for multiple `case`s then it is better form to declare it outside the `switch`:

```
   u8* name = malloc(20*sizeof(u8));
   switch(x) {
       case 1:
       // ...
```

If you leave the declaration where it is, then you must be careful to assign it a value before you use it, *after* the appropriate `case` label:

```
   switch(x) {
       u8* name;
       case 1:
       name = malloc(20*sizeof(u8));
       // ...
```

I urge you not to choose that approach, however, as it is poor style.

Comment: You can't put a declaration after a label.  GCC complains: `error: a label can only be part of a statement and a declaration is not a statement`.

Comment: Right you are, @JonathanLeffler.  Corrected,